# How to add content to the footer via the dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, footer

I've been trying to develop my own theme and in need of some help regarding adding content to the footer.

I need to add some text to the footer which could be changed via the admin panel. I know about the Advanced Custom Fields Plugin, but I would like to learn how this can be done without using it.

I've seen theme's where the footer(or other) changes can be made via *Appearance > Theme Options* section in the wordpress dashboard and I too would like to do the same.

I would be grateful if anyone could provide me a link or help me start with the process of doing so.

Regards,
Vinith Almeida

Answer (score 0):

You can install the **[OptionTree](http://wordpress.org/plugins/option-tree/)** plugin for WordPress. Then you can set your theme settings via the plugin, and then when you come to the footer section, you can use the **`ot_get_option()`** function to use the user value.

You can also watch this video for more help : **http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wS0WlHITVfc** or this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9JQJAu0X30

You can always register your own code for an option page that can contains options for your theme, but this requires deeper knowledge of the WordPress.